# Kubernetes Serenety Tests Ingress does not work with localhost

Tags: selenium, kubernetes, localhost, serenity-bdd

I'm working currently on local e2e tests.

**Setup**:

- My Windows Machine
- Working Kubernetes Cluster
- Deployed Services
- etc/hosts entries
- Selenium Tests with Cucumber

For the sake of clarity and because we will use different stages we want to change the redirect url endings from "testing" to "localhost" in all our e2e projects.

**hosts-file entry**

current

```
[MY IP ADDRESS] e2e.myproject.testing
```

to be

```
[MY IP ADDRESS] e2e.myproject.localhost
```

the

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-webclient
  name: my-webclient
  namespace: somenamespace
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "100m"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: "/app/"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: e2e.myproject.localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-myproject
          servicePort: 8080
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific

status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - hostname: localhost
```

Fun fact:
If I run my tests with the suffix "testing", "foobar", "deadbeef" whatever in the url and deployment files, things work fine. If i have replace it with "localhost" it doesn't work. And I get a connection error.

**Theory**:
Using anything other than "localhost" for the redirect-uris in the hosts file, the ingress points to the ip of my machine. But if I use localhost the ingress or deployments point to the ip of the virtual machine they are running in.

Can anyone verify that and know a solution? Might also solve some related issues we have ^^'

Comment: Could you test it once again using manual test (f.e. `curl`)? It could show if the problem is connected with K8S or with selenium.

Comment: We decided to follow how Docker does it and use "internal" instead of "localhost" for now

Comment: Could you explain that, please?

Comment: It seems Docker uses "internal" as they top level domain-naming for local stuff, instead of localhost.
So we thought we follow that work arround. And spare the pain

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/networking/

Comment: So, can I assume your problem is resolved?

Comment: yes. I can delete this post, if wished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify I am posting Community Wiki answer.

To resolve that problem you used `internal` instead of `localhost`.

As you wrote in comments section:

> It seems Docker uses "internal" as they top level domain-naming for local stuff, instead of localhost. So we thought we follow that workaround.

In [this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/networking/) one can find information about networking features in Docker Desktop for Windows.

See also [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) about DNS for Services and Pods.